# NSDate dateFromString adds multiple dates

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm really confused about NSDate and NSDateFormatter. I'm trying to parse the date from the twitter REST api 1.1. It seems like my DateFormat is wrong, however i'm almost 100% sure that it's correct. I get a null value after i do dateFromString

Here is my code

```
- (void)InitTwitterToMatchingArray
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss '+0000' yyyy"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [twitterParser1 getAmountOfTweets]; i++) {
        AktuelltMatching *amObject = [AktuelltMatching alloc];
        amObject.ID = i;
        amObject.type = @"twitter";
        NSString *dateString1 = [twitterParser1 getDateForIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"date BEFORE parse : %@", dateString1);
        amObject.date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString1];
        [AktuelltMatchingArray addObject:amObject];
        NSLog(@"date AFTER parse %@", amObject.date);
    }
}
```

This is my log

```
VasaSvahnFirstPrototype[481:907] date BEFORE parse : Fri Apr 26 22:44:06 +0000 2013
2013-06-25 20:03:56.505 VasaSvahnFirstPrototype[481:907] date AFTER parse (null)
2013-06-25 20:03:56.506 VasaSvahnFirstPrototype[481:907] date BEFORE parse : Fri Apr 26 22:43:48 +0000 2013
2013-06-25 20:03:56.507 VasaSvahnFirstPrototype[481:907] date AFTER parse (null)
2013-06-25 20:03:56.508 VasaSvahnFirstPrototype[481:907] date BEFORE parse : Wed Apr 10 13:51:06 +0000 2013
2013-06-25 20:03:56.509 VasaSvahnFirstPrototype[481:907] date AFTER parse (null)
2013-06-25 20:03:56.509 VasaSvahnFirstPrototype[481:907] date BEFORE parse : Fri Mar 22 14:51:45 +0000 2013
2013-06-25 20:03:56.510 VasaSvahnFirstPrototype[481:907] date AFTER parse (null)
2013-06-25 20:03:56.513
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: @H2CO3 please provide a helpfull answear to my problem.

Comment: @userXXX A "helpfull"? An "answear"? No.

Comment: NSDateFormatter dateFromString is notoriously finicky.  And it especially has trouble when you include the day of the week in the pattern.  You can try doing `setLenient:YES`, or strip the day of week from the input.

Comment: @HotLicks still nil. Man this is so frustrating, i've tried every possible DateFormatter string but i stil get nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your date format with this...

```
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below format: use 'E' only instead of 'EEE'.

[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"E MMM dd HH:mm:ss '+0000' yyyy"];

And Check out below link, it may help you:

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/simple-methods-for-date-formatting-and.html